# Integrating Spring MVC with Spring Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, tcp, spring-integration

I'm trying to connect my existing Spring MVC application with Spring integration but I can't find how to send a TCP message to an specific client.

I have lot of devices connected to my server over TCP and I'm using DirectChannel to get them connected.

Is there any way to specify the client who will receive the message when I call SimpleGatewy.send()?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Answer (score 0):

See the [tcp-client-server](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server) sample which uses a gateway - this can be invoked from any code, including a controller.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Gary. I already did something like that example but I don't know how can I send a message from the Controller to an specific connected client (since both are not connected directly). I've tried Routers and Bridges but didn't work so far (or probably I didn't know how to set up them). Is there any way to identify each connection by its ID in order to send a message using this id? I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I don't know how you'll identify specific clients but when they connect you can use an `ApplicationListener` to get an event which contains a `connectionId`. To route messages to a specific socket you need to set the `ip_connectionId` header to that value. You can do that via a `@Header` annotation on the gateway, or several other techniques. A constant for the header is in `IpHeaders.CONNECION_ID`. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events) for info about TCP events.

Comment: Hello again Gary,  thanks for your attention. I have moved a little bit forward with this. Now I'm trying to send arbitrary messages to multiple clients, I have all their connectionIds, but I don't know how can I send a message to each one of them since e.g TcpOutGate requires a connectionFactory which only receives ONE ip:port. How can I send a message to a client if I only have its connectionId?
Thank you.

Comment: You should probably start a new question and provide more details about what you are trying to do, showing configuration. I.e. Arbitrary messaging Vs. request/reply. The moderators here don't approve of extended comments.